# How to un-wedge go gRPC bidi-streaming server from the blocking Recv() call?

Tags: go, streaming, grpc

When serving a bidirectional stream in gRPC in golang, the canonical stream handler looks something like this:

```
func (s *MyServer) MyBidiRPC(stream somepb.MyServer_MyBidiServer) error {
    for {
        data, err := stream.Recv()
        if err == io.EOF {
            return nil // clean close
        }
        if err != nil {
            return err // some other error
        }
        // do things with data here
    }
}
```

Specifically, when the handler for the bidi RPC returns, that is the signal to consider the server side closed.

This is a synchronous programming model -- the server stays blocked inside this goroutine (created by the grpc library) while waiting for messages from the client.

Now, I would like to unblock this Recv() call (which ends up calling RecvMsg() on an underlying grpc.ServerStream,) and return/close the stream, because the server process has decided that it is done with this client.

Unfortunately, I can find no obvious way to do this:

- There's no Close() or CloseSend() or CloseRecv() or Shutdown()-like function on the bidi server interface generated for my service
- The context inside the stream, which I can get at with stream.Context(), doesn't expose user-accessible the cancel function
- I can't find a way to pass in a context on the "starting side" for a new connection accepted by the grpc.Server, where I could inject my own cancel function

I could close the entire grpc.Server by calling Stop(), but that's not what I want to do -- only this particular client connection (grpc.ServerStream) should be finished.

I could send a message to the client that makes the client in turn shut down the conection. However, this doesn't work if the client has fallen off the network, which would be solved with a timeout, which has to be pretty long to be generally robust. I want it *now* because I'm impatient, and, more importantly, at scale, dangling unresponsive clients can be a high cost.

I could (perhaps) dig through the grpc.ServerStream with reflection until I find the transportStream, and then dig out the cancel function out of that and call it. Or dig through the stream.Context() with reflection, and make my own cancel function reference to call. Neither of these seem well advised for future maintainers.

But surely these can't be the only options? Deciding that a particular client no longer needs to be connected is not magic space-alien science. How do I close this stream such that the Recv() call un-blocks, from the server process side, without involving a round-trip to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there is a great way to do what you are asking.  Depending on your goal, I think you have two options:

1. Run Recv in a goroutine and return from the bidi handler when you need it to return.  This will close the context and unblock Recv.  This is obviously suboptimal, as it requires care because you now have code executing outside the scope of the handler's execution.  It is, however, the closest answer I can seem to find.
2. If you are trying to mitigate the impact of misbehaving clients by instituting timeouts, you might be able to offload the work of this to the framework with [KeepaliveEnforcementPolicy](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#KeepaliveEnforcementPolicy) and/or [KeepaliveParams](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#KeepaliveParams).  This is probably preferable if this aligns with the reason you are hoping to close the connection, but otherwise isn't of much use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is not necessarily for misbehaving clients (although a full well-behaved client could be trusted to disconnect if I send it a message saying "please disconnect") -- evenso, keepalives will take a very long time before they kick in, if you want the connection to otherwise be robust.

Using another goroutine, and unblocking the incoming stream function to return when I want to close, seems to be the closest. As you suggest, there is now extra synchronization burden -- essentially, another Mutex cost to ensure these two routines don't race.